# Can I hide a table row in FitNesse Framework if the returned value is the expected value?

Tags: java, fitnesse

I'm trying to write acceptance tests using the FitNesse Framework (Slim) and I want, in the output result table after the acceptance tests have run, to see only the tests that failed.

I've searched for this topic but I can't find anything.
Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an exact answer, but using scenario with checks wrapped inside will kind of achieve what you want.

Scenario behaves like a macro, it can group multiple rows into a reusable components (with similar naming and parameters passing convention as fixture methods call). If there is checks wrapped inside a scenario, it will be collapsed in the result report and the whole row highlighted as green if all the checks inside pass; otherwise if any checks fail, it will expand, whole row highlighted in red and show the actual check/logic inside.